# How to declare savedInstanceState when using 'onStart' method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-preferences

Is it possible to use `if (savedInstanceState == null) {...}` in the `onStart` method for my fragment? Whenever I use it in the `onCreate` method, my fragment appears blank.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Boolean mCurrentValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:::: retrieving preferences");
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mCurrentValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("my_preference", false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:::: my_preference and mCurrentValue=" + mCurrentValue);
        if (mCurrentValue) {
            setTheme(R.style.MyDarkAppCompatTheme);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:::: setTheme:MyDarkAppCompatNoActionBarTheme");
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.MyLightTheme);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:::: setTheme:MyLightAppCompatNoActionBarTheme");
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        }
    }


    // in order to recreate Activity we must check value here because when we come back from another Activity onCreate doesn't called again
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Boolean mNewValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("my_preference", false);
        // if value differs from previous Theme, we recreate Activity
        if(mCurrentValue != mNewValue){
            recreate();
        }

        MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you need to access saved pieces of data, you'll need to extract them from the savedInstanceState Bundle in onCreate and save them as fields in your Activity. If you simply need to detect if this Activity was recreated (as is common with checking if the savedInstanceState is null), you can declare a boolean field in your Activity, and set it in onCreate when savedInstanceState is in scope, and then access it in onStart:

```
private boolean activityRecreated;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityRecreated = savedInstanceState != null;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    if (activityRecreated) {
       // code here
    }
}
```

EDIT: After getting more information about what state you're trying to save, try this:
You should have a field in your Activity that tracks the state of the ViewPager. This tag saves which tab the user is on. It could be a String tag or an Id (int) tag. You should save this by overriding onSaveInstanceState in your Activity:

```
private int tabIndex = 0 // NOTE: get this from your ViewPager's PagerAdapter
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tabIndex", tabIndex)
}
```

then, in onCreate, you can retrieve this value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      tabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("tabIndex", 0);
      // here, make sure your ViewPager's PagerAdapter is created and set it to this tab
    }
    // rest of your onCreate goes here
}
```

Saving the tab index in this manner will allow the activity to be recreated with the proper ViewPager tab visible.

Comment: Which parts of my code would need to go in the `if (activityRecreated) {...}` area?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause your fragment to appear blank. Are you sure your fragment has a layout with View in it?

Comment: The fragment has a ViewPager with 5 tabs but after trying your code, the fragment doesn't stay on the tab that I left off from :-(